# php echo first divs

Tags: php, regex

I don't want to be a help vampire: you don't have to code this for me.
I would mainly like to know I could make this possible.

How should I go about echoing the first 5 divs in a string?
I'd grab it using "file_get_contents", put it in a string, parse it, and then echo it.
How would I parse it? regex? some dom parser?

Like with this string:

```
<div class="div">1</div><div class="div">2</div><div class="div">3</div><div class="div">4</div><div class="div">5</div><div class="div">end!</div>
```

Many thanks,
cheers

Comment: what about using jQuery `.each`

Comment: @tq nice suggestion, but I asked for PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$string = '<div class="div">1</div><div class="div">2</div><div class="div">3</div><div class="div">4</div><div class="div">5</div><div class="div">end!</div>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$new_dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($string);

$count = 0;
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('div') as $node)
{
    $new_dom->appendChild($new_dom->importNode($node, TRUE));
    if (++$count >= 5)
        break;
}

echo $new_dom->saveHTML();
```

Instead of using jQuery or a 3rd party library, you can use PHP's [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class.

Comment: By far the best answer. I wanted raw PHP, and this is what I got. Thanks. :)

Comment: @SolèneLeVan, you welcome, please see edit. Optimized it so it will stop the loop after the 5th DIV, otherwise will needlessly loop to rest of DIVs.

Comment: @cryptic (BTW I'm solenelevan, I just had a short suspension for asking questions but it's now over). Ah, thanks for fixing! I hadn't tested the code so I assumed that it stopped after the 5th... BTW is the DOMDocument built into PHP, or do you have to install something external?

Comment: @DumbProducts It is bundled with PHP and enabled by default, and any host going out of there way to disable it would be a host you would not want to use.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- You could add root-Element to make the input-data valid XML and use
  libxml (DOM, simplexml, etc.). But the input data must be valid xml
  data(your sample data looks valid, needs only root element).
- use strpos with `><` as pattern and than substr. This is the faster way

**UPDATE:**
here sample code using strpos and substr:

```
$data = '<div class="div">1</div><div class="div">2</div><div class="div">3</div><div class="div">4</div><div class="div">5</div><div class="div">end!</div>';
$pos = 0;
for($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
    $pos = strpos($data, '><', $pos+2);
}
echo substr($data, $pos+1);
```

Comment: How could this be accomplished with strpos and substr? Would you mind posting a code example?

Comment: Thanks for the code! I like cryptic's answer best, but since you have 166 reputation, I'll give you a bounty of "50" reputation. (You probably know, but a bounty in STACKOVERFLOW is giving somebody some of your reputation. :) You can only reward  a bounty in 24 hours, so I'll do so in 24 hours. ;)

Answer (score 0):

[strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) and [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) is probably the best way to go if you want to stick to PHP.

Answer (score 0):

If the content of the div can contain substring "div" or other elements, it is better to use some parser. I recommend [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/), it is simple like jQuery, but for php.

Code will look like this:

```
echo pq('div:lt(5)', $string)->html()
```

Comment: phpQuery seems interesting, and I'm gonna look into it, but I'd prefer to accomplish this in raw PHP. You still get my upvote though. :)

Answer (score -1):

jquery slice

```
$(".topics .topic").slice(5).hide();
```

http://api.jquery.com/slice/

Comment: Nice script, could be of use... but I would pefer PHP. You still get my upvote, though. :)