# Echo last five divs

Tags: php, regex, domparser

How would I use php to `echo` the last 5 divs?

For example, this string:

```
<div style='df">cool</div><div>cooletre</div><div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div><div>5</div>
```

How would I do this? With a domparser, regex or what?

Could this be modified to accomplish this? The code here fetches the first five, yet I'd like to fetch the *last* five.

```
$string = '<div class="div">1</div><div class="div">2</div><div class="div">3</div><div class="div">4</div><div class="div">5</div><div class="div">end!</div>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$new_dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($string);

$count = 0;
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('div') as $node)
{
    $new_dom->appendChild($new_dom->importNode($node, TRUE));
    if (++$count >= 5)
        break;
}

echo $new_dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: Can you put them in an array?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP echo last 5 divs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14612775/php-echo-last-5-divs); the title is better though. Still not much expansion on why copy&pasted code sans attribution that's clearly meant for [extracting the **first** five elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14077304/php-echo-first-divs), or how you think it operates, or what *you tried yourself* to adapt it. SO isn't meant for plzsendtehcodez questions.

Comment: I have no clue about what to adapt. So your saying that any question, asking to be pointed in the right direction, is a "plzsendtehcodez"??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about with xpath?

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach($xpath->query('//div[position()>last()-5]') as $div){
  echo $dom->saveHTML($div);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A not so smart approach would be to count all opening `div` tags. Say you get n. Now find the n-5th `div` tag and from there, find the 5th closing `div` tag. Everything in between is what you're looking for.

The number of opening `div` tags can be obtained like that:

```
$num_div_tags = count(explode('<div', strtolower($string))) - 1;
```

From there, figuring out the 5th last `div` tag should be fairly straightforward.

The elegance of this solution perfectly fits the elegance of PHP.

In case you're not satisfied with this solution, you might as well come up with a simple finite state machine that iterates over the string char by char, detects opening and closing `div` tags, saves each pair in a circular list of length 5 and prints all list elements once the end of the string is reached.